# Clearing APC caches without crashing our scripts

Tags: php, apc

Currently, when we update our PHP code for our website, we have a script that calls apc_clear_cache on all servers, so that the new code will be used.

We also have some PHP scripts that run in the background on a separate server, processing some slower queries, and the like. The same script that calls apc_clear_cache also notifies the scripts to exit when they reach a reasonable stopping point.  The problem is that apc_clear_cache takes effect immediately, and some of the scripts that are not at a stopping point will reproducibly hang.

Does anyone know of a way around this problem aside from stopping all of these scripts (at the appropriate time), THEN calling apc_clear_cache, THEN restarting them all?

Comment: If you can get a stack trace, it might be worth filing a bug against APC.

Comment: It turns out that I was being silly--for our separate server running only scripts, there was no reason to have APC caching on at all.  I turned it off for that server--problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tell scripts to stop.
2. Clear APC cache.
3. Tell scripts to start.